# Retina support in Qt5 on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, retina

I'm writing a C++ graphical application using Qt 5.5.0 on OS X El Capitan on a Retina MacBook Pro. Text is pixelated throughout the application so I suspect that high DPI mode is not used. My Info.plist contains the following definition:

```
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
```

How do I enable high resolution mode (especially for text rendering) in a Qt application on OS X?

Comment: My Qt Widgets application is perfectly fine on retina, and I don't have that key in my .plist. I have no special keys, in fact. Just checked.

Comment: Just wanted to add that all text in the app is pixelated, even system dialogs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your info.plist has the `NSPrincipalClass` and `NSApplication` keys. According to the [Qt docs](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/25/retina-display-support-for-mac-os-ios-and-x11/), `NSHighResolutionCapable` is optional and true by default. Here's my entire plist for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="0.9">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>@ICON@</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Created by Qt/QMake</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>@TYPEINFO@</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>@EXECUTABLE@</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.my.@EXECUTABLE@</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you insist on specifying `NSHighResolutionCapable` manually, note that you did it wrong in your question. Here's the right syntax from the same docs:

```
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>NSApplication</string>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<string>True</string>
```

Comment: I tried your plist and manually correctly specifying `NSHighResolutionCapable` but it's still blurry/pixelated.

Comment: After testing some more, your answer is actually correct. My running directory contained an old copy of the .plist. Manually setting `NSHighResolutionCapable` was not necessary.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine: unless you need it, I'm fairly sure you can throw the plist away entirely. Should work without it as well.

Comment: Big thank you... super obvious (sarcasm, many thanks to Apple) add NSPrincipalClass equal to NSApplication and it indeed started to work.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to call `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)`
just after creating `QApplication` object to be able to use High DPI pixmaps. Read more here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#devicePixelRatio